# Why might performance of a Rust-sdl2 project be better while profiling?

Tags: performance, sdl2, profiling, rust, metal

I'm making a simple SDL2-based Rust game, on an OSX laptop. Graphics mostly involves drawing lots of colored squares to the screen. Performance is really slow for what I'm doing, so I decided to profile with [Flamegraph](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph). The weird thing is, when I run with flamegraph, performance improves dramatically, going from ~20-50ms/frame to more like 5-10ms/frame. What could possibly be causing this (and how can I take advantage of it)?

Here's the command I use to run the program normally:
`sudo CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG=true cargo run`

Here's the command I use to run the program with flamegraph:
`sudo CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG=true cargo flamegraph`

(Flamegraph requires some permissions to run, so I run them both with sudo for maximum comparability.)

Comment: Can you show us your compiler output? As I understand from consulting Rust-savvy colleagues, `CARGO_PROFILE_RELEASE_DEBUG`  controls only whether to emit debug info for a release build, not whether to compile as debug vs release, so it's possible Flamegraph is changing your build output. Look for a line that says something like `Finished foo [unoptimized + debuginfo]` or `Finished foo [optimized + debuginfo]`.

Comment: C Snover nailed it in his reply, and this comment helped me confirm that was what was going on. Thanks, DMGregory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Flamegraph README](https://github.com/flamegraph-rs/flamegraph/blob/main/README.md), it runs using the release profile by default:

```
# defaults to profiling cargo run --release
cargo flamegraph
```

So you must also run using the release profile, by running `cargo run --release`, to see the same performance.

Comment: That was it! Flamegraph was definitely setting the --release flag, which I, a n00b, did not know about. Thank you!

Comment: If this solved your problem, @sclamons, remember to click the checkmark icon on the left to mark the answer as "Accepted".

Comment: Ah, thanks for the reminder!